# jq: list users belonging to a specific group in array

Tags: jq

input json:

```
[
  {
    "user": "u1"
  },
  {
    "user": "u2",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": "100001",
        "name": "G1"
      },
      {
        "id": "100002",
        "name": "G2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "user": "u3",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": "100001",
        "name": "G1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to find all users belonging to specific group (searching by group `name` or group `id` in the `groups` array)

```
$ jq -r '.[]|select(.groups[].name=="G1" | .user)' json
jq: error (at json:27): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

Desired output format when searching of example group *G1* would be:

```
u2
u3
```

Additional question:
Is it possible to produce comma-separated output *u2,u3* without using external utilities like *tr*?

Comment: What is your desired output format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `?` as the [Optional Object Identifier-Index](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#OptionalObjectIdentifier-Index:.foo?) operator, you could do a select as below

```
map(select(.groups[].name == "G1")? | .user)
```

and un-wrap the results from the array by using `[]` at the end of the filter. To combine multiple selection conditions use the [boolean operators](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#and/or/not) with `and/or` inside the `select` statement

See [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/AytqH6IOxk) on jqplay

Comment: I finally use following command to prouce comma separated list. Is it possible to avoid external commands and produce such list by jq? jq -r 'map(select(.groups[].name == "LSY")? | .user)|@tsv'|tr -s '\t' ','

Comment: @Chris Use `@csv` instead of `@tsv`. This gives you commas directly instead of tabs (you don't have to invoke `tr` afterwards)

Comment: @pmf thank you, there is yet one problem when I use `@csv` ourput is with quotes so I need again using `tr -d \"`

Comment: @Chris That's because CSV demands it. But you can build your own format, `join(",")` for instance concatenates an array's string elements to a larger string using a given separator string (comma in this case) between the elements. But beware as you are left on your own when it comes to escaping "special" contents (like if a value by itself contained a comma and the like).

Answer (score 2):

Better enter your serach data from parameters using `--arg` and use `any` to avoid duplicate outputs if both inputs match:

```
jq -r --arg id "" --arg name "G1" '
  .[] | select(.groups | map(.id == $id or .name == $name) | any)? | .user
'
```

```
u2
u3
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_e16vHJW3D)

Comment: That way the OP could integrate this snippet using e.g. `--arg id "${id}" --arg name "${name}"` and doesn't have to bother which one actuallay has the search data. f course, if OP's question to search "by group name or group id" was to make an implementation easier but actually only needs one, one will suffice as well. -- In the end, all variables inside the filter also have to be declared outside.